# How to pass the parameter in ajax call of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I want  to pass the parameter in ajax call of  jquery data table, Here is my try:

```
var opts = {
    'ajax' : {
        'url': 'testing_ajax.php',
        'type': 'POST',
        'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //  'data': { field1: "hello", field2 : "hello2"} ,
        'data':function(data1) {
            return data1 = JSON.stringify(data1);  
        }
    },
    'pagingType': 'simple'
};
$('#example').dataTable(opts);
```

Comment: data attribute must be string, array or plain object. You have it function. How are you using this?

Comment: As of now I am not passing any parameter,If I uncommenting 'data': { field1: "hello", field2 : "hello2"}  , The result is not displaying..

Comment: I want to post the parameter in ajax call..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two other parameters in your `opts` object. Try include the `processing` option and `serverSide` option.

```
var opts = {
    'ajax' : {
        'url': 'testing_ajax.php',
        'type': 'POST',
        'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //  'data': { field1: "hello", field2 : "hello2"} ,
        'data': function(data1) {
            return data1 = JSON.stringify(data1);
        },
    }
    'pagingType': 'simple',
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true
};
```